# Tips to generate strong RSA keys

Tags: cryptography, rsa, encryption-symmetric, symmetric-key

Is there any documentation including tips to generate strong RSA key?

I mean not just ' use XXX utility with -X flag'.

I mean some rules in theory. For example, module n should be not less then 1024 bit, etc.

Can anybody tell me?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Try asking on http://crypto.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to your question, there is such documentation:
**Strong primes** are required by the ANSI X9.31 standard for use in generating RSA keys for digital signatures. This makes the factorization of n = p q using Pollard's p − 1 algorithm computationally infeasible. However, strong primes do not protect against modulus factorisation using newer algorithms such as Lenstra elliptic curve factorization and Number Field Sieve algorithm.

The version 4 **RSA Laboratories’ Frequently Asked Questions About Today’s Cryptography** was published in 1998 and can be found here ftp://ftp.rsa.com/pub/labsfaq/labsfaq4.pdf
Please pay attention to following questions:

**Question 3.1.4. What are strong primes and are they necessary for RSA?**

> In the literature pertaining to RSA, it has often been suggested that in choosing a key pair, one should use socalled
>   “strong” primes p and q to generate the modulus n. Strong primes have certain properties that make the
>   product n hard to factor by specific factoring methods; such properties have included, for example, the existence
>   of a large prime factor of p-1 and a large prime factor of p+1. The reason for these concerns is some factoring
>   methods (for instance, the Pollard p-1 and p+1 methods, see Question 2.3.4) are especially suited to primes p such
>   that p-1 or p+1 has only small factors; strong primes are resistant to these attacks.
>   However, advances in factoring over the last ten years appear to have obviated the advantage of strong primes;
>   the elliptic curve factoring algorithm is one such advance. The new factoring methods have as good a chance of
>   success on strong primes as on “weak” primes. Therefore, **choosing traditional “strong” primes alone does not
>   significantly increase security. Choosing large enough primes is what matters. However, there is no danger in
>   using strong, large primes, though it may take slightly longer to generate a strong prime than an arbitrary prime.**
>   It is possible new factoring algorithms may be developed in the future which once again target primes with
>   certain properties. If this happens, choosing strong primes may once again help to increase security.

**Question 3.1.5. How large a key should be used in RSA?**

> The size of an RSA key typically refers to the size of the modulus n. The two primes, p and q, which compose the
>   modulus, should be of roughly equal length; this makes the modulus harder to factor than if one of the primes is
>   much smaller than the other. If one chooses to use a 768-bit modulus, the primes should each have length approximately
>   384 bits. If the two primes are extremely close (identical except for, say, 100 - 200 bits), or more generally, if
>   their difference is close to any predetermined amount, then there is a potential security risk, but the probability
>   that two randomly chosen primes are so close is negligible.
>   The best size for an RSA modulus depends on one’s security needs. The larger the modulus, the greater the
>   security, but also the slower the RSA operations. One should choose a modulus length upon consideration, first, of
>   the value of the protected data and how long it needs to be protected, and, second, of how powerful one’s potential
>   threats might be.

As of 2010, the largest factored RSA number was 768 bits long (232 decimal digits). Its factorization, by a state-of-the-art distributed implementation, took around fifteen hundred CPU years (two years of real time, on many hundreds of computers). This means that, at this date, no larger RSA key has been factored. **In practice, RSA keys are typically 1024 to 2048 bits long**. Some experts believe that 1024-bit keys may become breakable in the near future; few see any way that 4096-bit keys could be broken in the foreseeable future. Therefore, it is generally presumed that RSA is secure if n is sufficiently large.

Answer (score 1):

Key strength generally follows current state of the art computing power. Key size is only part of a security plan. You also need to consider secure storage of your keys and how often you change keys.

Basically, you need to pick the widest key width that is compatible with the software you'll be using.

Currently, it is a good rule of thumb to go with minimum 2048-bit RSA as of 2014. It does depend on:

1. Speed and frequency of use
2. What you are protecting
3. Max width supported by your software

If having your key cracked is just an inconvenience that doesn't impact your finances or health, then you can err on the side of convenience. But if you really care about privacy, use the strongest key you can stand (no less than 2048).

A good doc is the OpenPGP Best Practices

https://we.riseup.net/riseuplabs+paow/openpgp-best-practices